# Build a sheet of graph paper with rotation

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
Graphics[{
  GeometricTransformation[
    {Gray, Dashed, 
     Table[InfiniteLine[{k, 0}, {0, 1}], {k, -6, 6}],
     Table[InfiniteLine[{0, k}, {1, 0}], {k, -6, 6}],}, 
     RotationMatrix[π/6]]}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Bold, PlotRange -> 5]
```

which produces this image:

[image]

Can anyone share a suggestion how I might make this a full sheet of graph paper (8.5x11) to print out?

Comment: Change the 6s to 12s and the 5 to 10?

Comment: I think you need to make it clear how you expect to fill an 8.5 x 11 page with a square image. Also, what should be the distance between to ruled lines on the printed page?

Comment: A large variety of [printable graph paper](https://www.printablepaper.net/) is available online (free download).  You may find an isometric graph paper, an isometric dot paper or a hypometric grid paper that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some code that produces a PDF file that should print something close to what you describe.

```
letter = {612, 792}; (* postscript point size *)
a4 = {596 , 842};
θ = ArcTan[2, 3];
vlines = Table[GeometricTransformation[
    InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {0, 1}],
    {RotationMatrix[θ], {k, 0}}], {k, -16, 16}];
hlines = Table[GeometricTransformation[
    InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {1, 0}],
    {RotationMatrix[θ], {0, k}}], {k, -16, 16}];
img = Graphics[{Gray, Dashed, vlines, hlines},
   Axes -> True,
   AxesStyle -> {{Bold}, {Thick}},
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-5, 5}},
   ImageSize -> letter];
Export["paper.pdf", img]
```

Some difference between your original code and this version are

- define `letter` and `a4` as paper sizes
- change angle so the lines go through axis integers
- apply different axis styles, just to see the effect
- use `BaseStyle` to set the font size
- use `ImageSize` to select either `letter` or `a4`
- `Export` the image as a PDF

The above seems to work.  That is, my PDF viewer recognizes the exported file as a letter size page.  Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. There are some nice things in here to learn.